# SHAP values for classification problem created with CARET in R

Tags: r, random-forest, caret, shap

I have created the model:

```
model_rf <- train(
  factor(les, levels = c("Yes", "No"))~ CAP+ TH+ KJ,
  data = train,
  metric = "ROC",
  method = "ranger",
  num.trees = 700,
  preProcess = c("center","scale"), 
  trControl = myControl,
  tuneGrid = tuneGrid,
  importance = 'permutation')
```

and when I try to calculate the SHAP values I get:

```
library(kernelshap)
library(shapviz)
xvars <- colnames(train[-1])
s <- kernelshap(model_glm, train, predict(model_glm, train, type = 'prob')$Yes, bg_X = train, feature_names = xvars)
```

Error in kernelshap.default(model_glm, newtr, predict(model_glm, train,  :
is.function(pred_fun) is not TRUE

In the documentation it mentions:Prediction function of the form function(object, X, ...), providing K ≥ 1
numeric predictions per row. Its first argument represents the model object,
its second argument a data structure like X. Additional (named) arguments are
passed via .... The default, stats::predict(), will work in most cases.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Try `s <- kernelshap(model_glm, X = train[-1], type = 'prob', bg_X = train)`, of course only if the first column of train is the response, and if train is small enough to serve as background data.